# Vim regex with back-reference to look-behind fails if a char follows the back-reference

Tags: regex, vim

I'm learning Vim-flavored regex and want to understand why this doesn't work.

Say I want to capture everything after a tag up to and including the closing tag:

```
<div>Test div</div>More words
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This works works but leaves off the trailing `>`:

```
/\v%(\<(\w+)\>)@<=.*\<\/\1
```

So I'd expect this to work, but it captures nothing:

```
/\v%(\<(\w+)\>)@<=.*\<\/\1\>
```

I know there are other ways to capture this, but I just want to learn why I can't include a character after the `\1` back-reference.

For convenience and my understanding, here's my understanding of the regex:

```
/\v  %(           # non-capturing
         \<       # <
         (        # captures group 1
            \w+   # 1+ alpha-numeric chars
         )
         \>       # >
      )@<=        # the match should be preceded by all of the above
     .*           # anything
     \<\/         # </
     \1           # that which was captured as group 1
     \>           # >
```

Comment: This might be a bug. However its often easier to use `\zs` instead of a positive look ahead. e.g. `\v%(\<(\w+)\>)\zs.*\<\/\1\>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this looks like a bug in the new NFA-based regular expression engine. When switching to the old engine, you have to swap the capturing group and use (all explained under `:help /\@<=`), but then, the matching works:

```
\%#=1\v%(\1)@<=.*\<\/(\w+)\>
```

Also because of this, the `:help` concurs with @PeterRincker that it's better to use `\zs` instead:

```
\v%(\<(\w+)\>)\zs.*\<\/\1\>
```

---

Please report this bug, see `:help bugs`. Basically, you can send the information via email, to the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php), or there's also a [bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/list).

Comment: Thanks, I've filed issue 334.

Comment: I was told in [issue 334](https://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/detail?id=334#c1) that it's not a bug -- and indeed, :help \@<= says the part  after '\@<=' is checked first, so \1 doesn't work to reference \(\) inside the preceding atom. Interesting, then, that my other example works (but only with \#=2, with \#=1 the \1 doesn't do anything).

Comment: @mgiuffrida: That's only with the _old_ engine, it is a bug in the new one; I've replied in the issue to clarify that.